# Search database in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I wanted to be able to Search in the database at any table whether it is the First Name, Last Name, Middle Name, Etc... the problem is, I always get from query an empty results

This is my attempt

I use the HTML Form for the User to Search With clicking necessary datum.

```
<table border='0' align='right'>
    <tr>
        <td >
            <select name='SEARCH' id='SEARCH'>
                <option value='ID_NO' selected='selected'>ID Number</option>
                <option value='FNAME'>First Name</option>
                <option value='LNAME' >Last Name</option>
                <option value='MNAME'>Middle Name</option>
                <option value='DATE'>Birthday</option>
                <option value='SEX'>SEX</option>
                <option value='AGE'>Age</option>
                <option value='STATUS'>Status</option>
                <option value='TEL_NO'>Landline Number</option>
                <option value='ADDRESS'>Address</option>
                <option value='OCCUPATION'>Occupation</option>
                <option value='REFERRED_BY '>Referrals</option>
                <option value='itResult'>Result</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td rowspan =2><input name='SUBMIT' type='SUBMIT' id='SUBMIT' value='Search!'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input name='INPUT' type='text' id='INPUT'></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Then the datum that was entered is pass through here and check to the database

```
<?php
    print "<center><H2>Search User</H2></center>";
    $ID_CHECK = clean($_POST['chck']);
    $SEARCH = clean($_POST['SEARCH']);
    $INPUT   = clean($_POST['INPUT']);

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE '$SEARCH' = '$INPUT'" ) or die('Error, query failed');
    if(!mysql_num_rows($result)) {
        print "<BR>There is no $INPUT in the Database <BR><A HREF ='SearchUser.php'>Go Back</A>";
        exit();
    }
    else {
        $row_array = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
?>
```

The Problem is, I always get an empty query and that 
I think using this is wrong

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE '$SEARCH' = '$INPUT'" )  or die('Error, query failed');
```

is there another way? JavaScript perhaps?

My Clean Function does this.. it cleans the value of the data I think

```
<?php
    function clean($str) {
        $str = @trim($str);
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            $str = stripslashes($str);
        }
    return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
    }
?>
```

Comment: I see the problem in, $SEARCH = clean($_POST['SEARCH']); no data is being passed from the form .. it seems <select name='SEARCH' id='SEARCH'> is not working for me

Comment: you should be using PDO => http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/

Comment: Where's your `<form>` element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is that in your query you are comparing two strings.  This should work:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE $SEARCH = '".$INPUT."'")  or die('Error, query failed');
```

I removed the single quotations from $SEARCH.

Comment: I realized the `$SEARCH` has no value. The `<select name='SEARCH' id='SEARCH'>` not giving any value to `$SEARCH`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what does your `clean` function do? If it's quoting your content, you may be ending up with extra quotes with '$SEARCH'. Secondly, you may want to have a look at MySQL's [LIKE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) comparison if you want to do a more thorough search.

Comment: `function clean($str) { $str = @trim($str); if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) { $str = stripslashes($str); } return mysql_real_escape_string($str); }`

Answer (score 0):

Try using concatenation:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT *  FROM userinfo WHERE concat(//add the database rows here) LIKE '%$something%' ");
```